# How to implement Perl hashes in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have been looking through many sites and tutorials, and the Apple documentation, and still haven't found a solution: it seems to me that NSArray, NSDictionary and their mutable counterparts are not at all resembling the simple functionalities of a Perl hash. I hope I am wrong of course.

What I need: a mutable structure of **dynamic keys** and values (1 key - 1 value, as simple as that)! I mean, I don't know keys in advance and I need to easily check whether a key exists and if it exists retrieve a value or update it, if it does not exist enter the new key with the new value. And I need the values to be **floats**, not objects nor arrays. After I finished populating the structure I need to be able to retrieve the keys and finally looping through the values by the keys I retrieved.

All of this is easily accomplished in Perl with the following:

```
    my %expenses;

    if (exists $expenses{$key}) {
       $expenses{$key} += $amount;
    } else {
       $expenses{$key} = $amount;
    }

[...]
```

Is there someone who could tell me how to implement something similar in objective-c without using primitive types?

Thank you so much for any help.
Fabrizio

Comment: Why can't you use `NSMutableDictionary`? Your code won't be quite as short as the Perl version, but I believe it can do everything you need. Unfortunately it will also make you wrap your floats in an `NSNumber`.

Comment: I thought I could not use it, I thought I tried the right way, but I was wrong as the two other posters here showed me...I am glad I was wrong :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
NSString *key=@"fish";
NSMutableDictionary *expenses = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
float amount=22.0;

[expenses setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:amount/2] forKey:key];

if ([expenses objectForKey:key]) {
    [expenses setObject:
         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:
             [[expenses objectForKey:key] floatValue] + amount] forKey:key];
} else {
    [expenses setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:amount] forKey:key];
}

NSLog(@"expenses: %@",expenses);
```

Comment: Well carrot-top, what better comment can I put here than lines from my debug console? Ops...I can't put that many chars but it works smoothly! Thank you so much, I was stuck with creating an NSArray of NSDictionaries and couldn't see the easy way. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Ah...forgot to ask two questions: 1) what is the meaning of amount/2? 2) My key is actually a combination of three keys, could I use them and perform searches on any combination of them? I mean key1 and key2, key1 and key2 and key3, only key3, etc...?

Comment: The `amount/2` was just a random number to get the first part of the if clause to fire.

Answer (score 4):

The Cocoa and Core Foundation collection classes are generally oriented towards storing objects rather than primitive values; the usual solution to a problem like yours is to wrap the floats in NSNumber objects. And unfortunately, the syntax for getting and setting the objects is more verbose than Perl's

Other than that, an NSMutableDictionary should do exactly what you want. The keys can be any string, or any other object that can be copied (i.e. it conforms to the NSCopying protocol), you can get a list of all keys, and you can check if a key "exists" in the dictionary by simply trying to fetch the corresponding value. The code corresponding to your example could look something like this:

```
// NB: there no autovivification in Objective-C. Be sure to initialize this somewhere
// before using it!
NSMutableDictionary *expenses;

if ([expenses objectForKey:key]) {
    // This *could* be done in one statement. But it would be very long, so I split
    // it in two for clarity.
    float currentValue = [[expenses objectForKey:key] floatValue];
    [expenses setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentValue + amount] forKey:key];
} else {
    [expenses setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:amount] forKey:key];
}
```

Comment: You need to add some sort of `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` code to instantiate expenses.

Comment: Thank you Anomie, your answer was pointing in the right direction, carrot-top made it even simpler with his code but you both helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @carrot-top: Duh. I pointed that out in the *nota bene* comment.

Comment: I was pointing out for the potential benefit of a beginner in Obj-C. I am sure that you knew it perfectly well. :-)